# Google Analytics: call _setAccount on already created tracker object with _gat._createTracker

Tags: google-analytics, push

I'm a bit confused with the sample code at Google Analytics (who isn't?).
In their example code they write:

```
_gaq.push(function() {
    var pageTracker = _gat._createTracker("UA-XXXXX-X", "myTracker");
});
```

And then later...

```
_gaq.push(["myTracker._setAccount", "UA-XXXXX-X"]);    // #1

_gaq.push(function() {
    var myTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName("myTracker");
    myTracker._trackEvent(...);
});
```

I don't understand why they set the tracker's account (#1), because the tracker object is created by account, and I get the tracker object by its name.

[Asynchronous Tracking Usage Guide, Pushing Functions](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/asyncUsageGuide.html)

Does anybody have any experience with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this my self by sending different tracking events to see which one that are accepted by GA, and all of them were received. So in conslusion, in my case (code above), it does not matter whether he account is set on the created tracker object or not. But still, its kind of confusing that it is possible, and yet there is no good explaination from Google!